# How can I displayed conditional data in the DataTable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable

I am currently fetching the data using the axios get method and setting it in data variable using useState hooks in the json object.
But I have one extra column in by DataTable which is the conditional on two parameter on json data.

Example:

If my json data is

```
{
        "name": "Xyz",
        "email_id": "cse@gmail.com",
        "check_out": null,
        "data": null,
        "check_in": null
    }
```

Then I had one column in DataTable with name Status whose work is to display p**resent when check_in time is not null** an Display **absent when check_in time is null**

I did this with ternary operator and the simple Table using bootstrap but i am confused how can we check the condition at the DataTable react library.

Here is my code for better understanding...

```
export default function Table() {

  const [data,setData]=useState([]);

  const columns = [
    {
        name: 'name',
        selector: row => row.name,
    },
    {
        name: 'email_id',
        selector: row => row.email_id,
    },
    {
      name:'Status',
      selector:row=>row.Status
    }
];


  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("view").then((response)=>{
      setData(response.data);
     
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  },[]);  
return (
    <DataTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}/>
  )
}
```

Here is what i wanted (what i did using Bootstrap)
[image]

Comment: I am not sure how datatable works but sounds like you could either format your data to just send the data you want to the table, either use this : https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Comment: i actually want check in details so that i can mark a person present or absent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const data = [
  {
      "name": "Xyz",
      "email_id": "cse@gmail.com",
      "check_out": null,
      "data": null,
      "check_in": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
    "check_out": null,
    "data": null,
    "check_in": null
  },
];

const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    selector: row => row.name,
  },
  {
    name: 'Email',
    selector: row => row.email_id,
  },
  {
    name:'Status',
    selector: row => row.check_in ? 'Present' : 'Absent'
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks its working can you explain we what is the significance of the selector and how this flow is working so that I can understand concept

Comment: Selector function is used to display data for that cell. Selector takes your data object as parameter (row) for that particular row and allows us to specify what value should be returned. We can even return html like
selector: row => row.check_in ? <div classs="myclass">Present</div : <div className="myotherclass">Absent</div>
Please refer docs for more customisation: https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/api-columns--page